# how to copy files from one directory to other in batch command

Tags: batch-file

I wish to copy a file with extension .dyn which is located in each subfolder of main folder(T15_finished). I wish to copy it into respective subfolder at other location(T15). I have created that location using xcopy command. Here, .dyn file is being copied successfully in respective subfolder in T15 folder(see below code). Now, I have a file which has extension as .dynain which is located in the same subfolder as .dyn. And .dynain file is also getting copied which i don't want.
Please see following code which i have created. Can anyone tell me whats wrong ?

```
@echo off

xcopy D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\CPW\T15_finished  D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\FRESH_SPRINGBACK\CPW\T15 /t
xcopy /e D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\CPW\T15_finished\*.dyn D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\FRESH_SPRINGBACK\CPW\T15

pause
```

Answer (score 2):

Short file names. If you do a `dir /x` in the folder containing the `.dynain` file, you will see the 8.3 filename generated for the file, and it will have `.dyn` extension.

If you know the extensions of the conflicting files, you can use `robocopy` with `/xf` switch to indicate the files (`*.dynain`) to exclude, or you can generate a exclude file to use with `xcopy /exclude:file` (see `xcopy /?` for a explanation)

Or, you can generate the list of files to exclude

```
(for /f "tokens=" %%a in (
    'dir /s /b "D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\CPW\T15_finished\*.dyn" ^| findstr /v /i /e /l ".dyn"'
) do @echo(%%~nxa)>excludedFiles.txt

xcopy /exclude:excludedFiles.txt /e D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\CPW\T15_finished\*.dyn D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\FRESH_SPRINGBACK\CPW\T15
```

Or (as posted by foxidrive), copy all and then delete the non needed files.

Answer (score 1):

The short filename is being matched as well as the long filename.  That is the reason.

A solution is to use another command to delete the files:

```
del /s "D:\Master\SPRINGBACK\FRESH_SPRINGBACK\CPW\T15\*.dynain"
```

Comment: Yes.. I did with del command.. But I wanted to ask if there is possibility.. Thanks a lot..